# jbuilderでwrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

jbuilderでwrong number of arguments (0 for 1)というエラーが出ました。

usersとitemsをjsonで返すだけのプログラムで、なぜかitemsの方だけにでます。

`route.rb`

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, only: [:index]
    resources :items, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

`api/v1/items_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::ItemsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @items = Item.all
   end
end
```

`views/api/v1/items/index.json.jbuilder`

```
json.items @items
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `itemの方にだけ出る`、ということは、Item の Model を json に変換するときにエラーになっていると推測できます。Item Model のコードを記載できないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Modelに原因があることは思いつきませんでした。。
Item Modelに引数が必要なメソッドを定義しているのが原因でした。
ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 問題が解決した場合は自分で回答を投稿してください（http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer）。その後48時間待って、回答を承認してください（http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers）。回答が承認されないとトップページに繰り返し表示されてしまうためです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Item Modelに引数が必要なメソッドを定義しているのが原因でした。